# You're - can it be past and present tense?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, tenses

The contraction for *you are* is *you're*, which is present tense. Can it also be past tense, as in *you were*?

Take this sentence, for example, "you're awfully late getting home."

I assume (rightfully?) that it could mean either "you are awfully late getting home (now)" or "you were awfully late getting home (last evening)."

Are these both grammatically correct in American English? If they are, how can one tell which they are meant to represent, if possible? Does it always depend completely on context?

Comment: Hint: No. ........

Comment: @TinfoilHat The question was whether it was grammatically correct to contract  *you were*.  Of course it is: native speakers do it all the time and therefore it must be. Your duplicate has nothing about grammar or grammaticality. It can't, since it's only referencing writing, while grammaticality is a function of speech alone. The contraction of *you are* is a homophone of *your*, but the contraction of *you were* is not a homophone of *your* because it sounds different. Therefore there are two separate contractions, both fully grammatical in the speech of native speakers of American English.

Comment: @tchrist There is no grammar in writing? That's news to me. There's no apostrophe in speech either, so what are (what're) we talking about?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Y’es, grammer has nothing two doo with righting. Say it aloud: it's perfectly grammatical. QED. I can you easily things write with grammar questionable despite nothing that has with spelling nor punctuation amiss to be doing appearing.

Comment: @TinfoilHat No punctuation in speech? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eixevXANKAo

Comment: @tchrist As you wish, but *you're*, appearing on a "page," in writing, "never" means *you were*.

Comment: In writing, it can only mean "you are". "You were" cannot normally be contracted like that.

Comment: Yes. That's a wrule of English righting. Has nothing to do with English language. English could be written in Chinese characters or Devanagari and it'd still be English. Though the idea is innately silly, because installed base.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you're

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about grammar and grammaticality, I can only presume you are asking about speech, not writing. Grammar is only a property of speech, of what you can hear. That being the case, the answer to your question is that sure, people do indeed make a natural contraction for both tenses here. It just doesn’t sound the same in both tenses, which is how you can tell one from the other.

Imagine that you had a parent saying this to their child:

#### [ˈjʊwɚːˈpʰɻɪdiˈlɛjʔˈgɪʔn̩ˈhowmˈlæjəsˈnʌjʔˈkʰɪd]

Because the kid got home pretty late last night. Clear enough, right?  That sentence is perfectly grammatical with the contraction as the first word, and its use in the past tense is completely obvious because it sounds different that way — and because it specifies *last night*. So people really do use this—in speech, where nobody bats an eyelash at routine compressions like these.

An **uncontracted** *you were* would have been quite different: **[ˈjuw.wɚː]**. It would have had a long (close) vowel and two words with a geminated semi-consonant glide [w] separating them, not just one all run together with its vowel shortened up and a lot less of a glide.

The ***present tense* contraction [jʊɹ]** doesn’t have a long tense vowel here; it’s more lax. But the ***past tense* contraction [ˈjʊwɚː]** would have a little bit longer vowel to start with (although maybe still just as lax) with a semi-consonant glide finishing it, and then a more drawn-out rhotic at the end specifically to distinguish the tense. It would probably even be perceived as having two syllables with the [w] glide between them, which is why I’ve written it that way.

But **how you choose to *write* that** is  completely up to you: good luck! Whatever you choose won’t affect its grammaticality one tiny bit, not even if you were to write that contraction as *Ewwer*. We simply don’t have any agreed-upon way to write almost any of the many, many things that we really do say in real-world English speech.  This is one of them.

But it surnuff might gitcha talk tabout, doncha know. :)